# How do i get the getMajorUnit value from a plotted graph using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-charts

i have plotted a graph successfully. Now i want to know the values of majorunit and minorunit using java apache poi.

Something like

```
XDDFValueAxis axis =
axis.getMajorUnit()
```

is not returning the value which is used in the graph which was set automatically

Is there any workaround to get the  major unit / minor unit / upper bound / lowerbound values

Comment: What value is used in the graph? I suspect it is the auto (default) value. This value is not explicitly set. So you will not get something from `axis.getMajorUnit` until you have explicitly set something using `axis.setMajorUnit` or the chart has an axis major unit explicitly set in GUI.

Comment: i havent set any values in the majorunit. The graph is plotted successfully. Now i want to get the default value

Comment: There is no method to get the default value as it is not explicitly set. So `Excel` determines the default value while rendering the graph.